# What does 放 mean in contexts such as 你给我放聪明点 or 你给我放老实点?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I often hear people say

> 你给我放聪明点

or

> 你给我放老实点

I understand 放 usually means to place or to release, but in this context it is really confusing. Do people mean to place things clever or honest in the speaker?

Another example is 放肆. The 放 is hard to understand.

Comment: instead of 点（儿）often with 些: 现代汉语词典：放（１５）控制自己的行动，采取某种态度，达到某种分寸：～明白些｜～稳重些｜脚步～轻些 bkrs：(22) 要求对方采取某种态度 [behave]。 如: 放尊重些; 放明白些

Comment: where '放' means 'to be' or 'to act as'. 你给我放聪明点 = you should do it in a wise way.  放肆 means wanton.

Comment: Very often it is near impossible to translate one language to another with absolute fidelity. Sometimes, not always of course, the "meaning" or "spirit" rather than the actual words used is to be translated, in order to avoid some of the hilarious English / Chinese translations one sees in China recently.

So, I think 放 as used in 放聪明点 would sound better in English if translated as "show" and 点 as " a bit"; so we get -- "...show a bit of intelligence", which actually captures the meaning, spirit of this sarcastic rebuke. 

"show" works equally well with 放老实点, "...show a bit of honesty"

Comment: 放肆 of course is in a different category as the two words must always be read together to give it its particular meaning of behaving in a morally offensive way.

Answer (score 2):

放老实点 means put in a honest way. Similarly, 放聪明点 means put in a wise way.

放肆 means your behavior cross the line people just can not tolerate. it's kind of talk-down.

放 is such a common word that it can be used in lots of circumstances. There will be a lot of meaning you will get from a dictionary.

For example, 放鞭炮，放牛，放纵，放荡，绽放， 放 in these phrases means differently.

Answer (score 0):

'放 usually means to place or to release' your consider is right, but 放肆 can’t split，because 放肆 is a entirety, for example 你太放肆了, translate to english you are realy lack of courtesy.

about 你给我放聪明点 or 你给我放老实点，放 expression to rebuke,